# Can't install Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sql-server-data-tools

I get the following errors when I want to install the Microsoft Server Data Tools:

```
[1F7C:1F80][2016-10-19T10:22:28]: Error 0x80044000: Process returned error: 0x80044000
[1F7C:1F80][2016-10-19T10:22:28]: Error 0x80044000: Failed to execute EXE package.
[1D9C:1DA0][2016-10-19T10:22:28]: Error 0x80044000: Failed to configure per-machine EXE package.
[1D9C:1DA0][2016-10-19T10:22:28]: Applied execute package: DEV14ISOSHELLLP, result: 0x80044000, restart: None
[1D9C:1DA0][2016-10-19T10:22:28]: Error 0x80044000: Failed to execute EXE package.
[1F7C:1F80][2016-10-19T10:22:28]: Removing cached package: DEV14ISOSHELLLP, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\F1CC37BA16D64D101B05001079E51654F38CCE76\
[1F7C:1F80][2016-10-19T10:22:32]: Removed bundle dependency provider: {c2e27636-4c63-47f9-b361-8c61ea7cd504}
[1F7C:1F80][2016-10-19T10:22:32]: Removing cached bundle: {c2e27636-4c63-47f9-b361-8c61ea7cd504}, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{c2e27636-4c63-47f9-b361-8c61ea7cd504}\
[1D9C:1DA0][2016-10-19T10:22:32]: Apply complete, result: 0x80044000, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
```

to get the Tab Item "Server Object Explorer" and the whole funcionality.

- Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition
- And the installer official from Microsoft page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who also look for a solution, back then i fixed it with uninstalling VS and reinstalling it with the additional tools checked in the "main" setup.

Answer (score 1):

had the exact same error message. I think the installation fails while installing an additional  language pack which will be done automatically if you install the SSDT in a different language as your VS Installation.

It finally worked when i used the installer with the same language than my VS-installation, which can be found here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/mt186501

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Maybe people still looking for solution of this, I was able to solve this by updating my windows specifically with updates of
[KB2919355](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2919355/windows-rt-8.1,-windows-8.1,-and-windows-server-2012-r2-update-april-2014).

once I installed those updates reboot, restarted the SSDT installation all worked out.

hope it helps others that looking for the solution.

regards